# HTTP POST on Android to PHP throws NullPointer Error

Tags: php, android, json, android-json

I want to make a simple HTTPRequest to a php script for a user registration with some parameters(name,email,password, etc). I have tried many tutorials from internet but nothing works for me. HTTP POST throws `NullpointerException` . in backend also it shows null.

My code is :

```
        //JSON Node Names

        private static final String TAG_ID = "status";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "code";
        private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "message";
        //POST data
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", "Steve"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_email", "jjdnjdn"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_password", "dcds"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_phone_number", "2343"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("club_member_id", "24"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     //For receiving response
// Creating new JSON Parser
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            Log.e("Data", String.valueOf(json));
            try {
     String id = json.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = json.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = json.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), id , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), name , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), email , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Logcat Error

```
      E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
      E/Data: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

PHP code

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

getting null array.

Comment: do you try to call url in browser ?

Comment: can you post your json

Comment: @Sree: yes i did it works well. So its not the problem with URL.

Comment: @mohit i've tried this `echo jsone_encode($_POST)` but will get a null array

Comment: does it showing json on browser?

Comment: yes what you are getting when you call in your browser

Comment: @Sree CURL output is success . verified the PHP script with CURL. Its working fine

Comment: UPDATED THE PHP CODE

Comment: so can you able to post that json plz

Comment: @Sree : `{"status":false,"code":"101","message":"Cannot find a POST request in register"}`

Comment: this is why you are getting null, plz try to correct your php side to get a valid response and check inside your code for "status":"true"

Comment: but by using CURL we have done a successful registration.

Comment: maybe, you POSTED actual data via curl, but not with the java code, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url) seems to GET instead of POST (and anyway you haven't use httppost or referenced it anyhow from jParser, so it couldn't POST your data for sure.

In th ephp you might also need to send a correct Content-type header before you echo the json body, as jParser might depend on it.

Comment: So how could i use Httppost?

Comment: you can google "android http post" and chose one of the thousands of answers. Even here on stackoverflow you'll fund at least 100 examples. When you get the json as a String you can then parse it with JsonParser

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

**App Side**

```
private static final String TAG_ID = "status";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "code";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "message";


ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", "Steve"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_email", "jjdnjdn"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_password", "dcds"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_phone_number", "2343"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("club_member_id", "24"));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

try {

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){

     JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

     String id = jsonResponse .getString(TAG_ID);
     String name = jsonResponse .getString(TAG_NAME);
     String email = jsonResponse .getString(TAG_EMAIL);

}

} catch (JSONException e) {

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

**Server Side**

```
<?php


file_put_contents(__DIR__."/request_log.txt", "Request : ".json_encode($_REQUEST));

if(!empty($_REQUEST))
{

$user_name = $_REQUEST["user_name"];
$user_email = $_REQUEST["user_email"];
$user_password = $_REQUEST["user_password"];
$user_phone_number = $_REQUEST["user_phone_number"];
$club_member_id = $_REQUEST["club_member_id"];


/*

Add your code

*/

$result = array("status" => "status_value", "code" => "code_value", "message" => "message");

file_put_contents(__DIR__."/request_log.txt", "Result : ".json_encode($result), FILE_APPEND);

echo json_encode($result);

}

?>
```

Comment: logcat shows `Cannot find a POST request in register` .. in PHP `$data = json_decode($_POST["data"], true);` is empty

Comment: Did you get any exception in app side? Please log all exceptions and check if any exceptions come.

Comment: NullpointerException on JSONObject.getString() comes because response from server is null. Please log jsonParams.toString() before this => ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

Comment: i logged Params as ` Log.e("Params", String.valueOf(jsonParams.toString()));` just after ` ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jsonParams.toString()));`  it logged well as `E/Params: {"user_name":"Steve","user_email":"jjdnjdn","user_password":"dcds","user_phone_number":"2343","club_member_id":"24"}`

Comment: I have updated server side script. Please check request_log.txt after posting request to server from app.

Comment: yes,in request_log.txt . data is correctly write as json. So is this the problem with java code.?

Comment: Can you please comment request_log.txt data?

Comment: request_log.txt  shows `{"user_name":"Steve","user_email":"jjdnjdn","user_password":"dcds","user_phone_number":"2343","club_member_id":"24"}`

Comment: Ok. Now replace all $_POST to $_REQUEST. Also log final responce to same log file and comment the result

Comment: in Logcat im getting an error `E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: I have updated server script. Please show me data in request_log.txt

Comment: When decoding JSOn in php side,the data is not getting as an array.

Comment: Oops!! Updated app and server side codes. Try this and show me your request_log.txt

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99378/discussion-between-ijas-ahamed-and-rubin-nellikunnathu).